# HTTP Status 404 - Not Found on call of Servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, http-status-code-404

I am getting HTTP Status 404 when i call Servlet from JSP page.

**Here is web.xml :**

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Register</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>servlets.dataio.registration.Register</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Register</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Register</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**Here is effective code of JSP:**

```
<form name="admin-form" action="Register" method="POST">
```

**Error message:**

```
HTTP Status 404 - Not Found

type Status report

message: Not Found

description: The requested resource is not available.
```

**Directory structure is:**

```
Web Pages --> Pages --> Registration --> registerpage.jsp
```

I have tried Clean and Building project.
I am using NetBeans IDE and GlassFish server

Comment: Clean & build project and try to depoly & run.

Comment: Is the JSP file under some folder? It should be just under `Web Pages` since you're using `action="Register"`

Comment: <form name="admin-form" action="/Register" method="POST">

Comment: @J.Lucky No, JSP is not just inside `Web Pages`.

Comment: Then that's why you're getting an error. Please post your directory structure so that I can help you fix it.

Comment: Directory Structure is: `Web Pages --> Pages --> Registration --> registerpage.jsp`

Comment: Servlet package structure is `servlets.dataio.registration.Register.java`

Comment: @J.Lucky I have posted directory structure..

Comment: Yes, please try out my answer. Hope it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
action="../../Register"
```

To make your page relative to where the Servlet is.

`../` means one directory up. And based on the directory structure you've posted, it's two folders down under the `Web Pages` so you'll need two `../` to make it relative to where your Servlet is, which is, based `<url-pattern>/Register</url-pattern>` meaning just under `Web Pages`

Answer (score 1):

The `action` attribute is using by default relative path, so if your jsp is available at `http://yourHost/yourApp/pathToJsp/registerpage.jsp` then your relative servlet path is `http://yourHost/yourApp/pathToJsp/Register` which is not correct.

You have two choices:

- use relative path like J.Lucky suggested - but its error prone, as you have to fix it in every jsp, or if you move jsp in you directory structure
- use absoulute path - start with / - but you need to include your context-root name, like this - `/yourContext/Register`. If you want to avoid hard coding context root you can use  request.getContextPath() method, like this `action='<%=request.getContextPath()%>/Register'`

Answer (score 0):

try action="/Register"

and this line is 'cause message must be at least 30 chars

Comment: any other servlets registered?